# How to Update PHPmyadmin to 4.0.4.1 on a Debian VPS

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to update from phpmyadmin 3.3.7deb7 to the latest or closest possible to 4.0.4.1. I dislike the look of 3.3.7 and would really like to update. But not knowing how to do much in a Linux environment, I've looked on Google and other search engines. But nothing is simple enough to follow for a "noob".

Any help is greatly appreciated ;D

I am on VPS which uses debian-6.0-x86 64-cvps-base

Comment: Can you not just use apt-get? The command would be `apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin`.

Comment: What is your setup exactly? One click (LAMMP) or Manual (apache/nginx/other as your webserver)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for your version of Debian the packaged version is the 3.x branch of phpMyAdmin, so relying on the packaged version isn't going to work for you.

There are theoretically ways to force installing a package from another version in to yours, but I would not advise that (unless you're quite careful you can end up with a mess of dependencies).

What I'd suggest is simply to remove the Debian packaged version and install your own. You can download it from https://phpmyadmin.net, and installation takes only a few minutes and minimal configuration. You can learn a lot about the process from the [phpMyAdmin documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install).

Good luck!